# How do I get permission for my second internal HDD drive ? [22.04 LTS]

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, 22.04

So I've bought a new personal computer, with a 1TB SSD and a 4TB HDD drive, pre installed with un-activated Windows. So I decided to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and completely remove Windows.

At the moment I'm having trouble using my second drive and I can't even understand the reason. I can't copy files there or create new ones with `touch test.txt`. I tried to re-install and change what directory I'm doing the partition for the second drive, no change. I followed some instructions about `sudo mkdir /hdd`, `sudo chmod -R 777 /hdd` edit `/etc/fstab` and `mount -a`, that didn't work either. `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` produced an error *Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda1.*

I'm not experienced in Ubuntu so it's not impossible I would mess up at any point, so all and any answers will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you already remove Windows? Windows was probably hibernated and locked the drive. Turn off "Fast Startup" in Windows so it shuts down properly.

Comment: If the device is new and there is no data you need on the drive, then you can probably just wipe the whole thing and format it

Comment: To add to @Esther 's comment, format the second internal hard drive as `ext4` the default format used by Ubuntu as you don't have Windows anymore. You may use the app called **Disks** in Ubuntu. Windows has the habit of using Fast Startup as the default. Which keeps hard drives in "dirty" mode. Which in turn makes Ubuntu mount them in the "read only" mode, preventing writing to these drives, so that no data from Windows is lost.

Comment: @user68186 interestingly, it appears the drive is mounted as read-write ("Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda1"). So possibly the issue is just with NTFS file permissions vs Linux file permissions.

Comment: For sure you should not have an ntfs drive that cannot be periodically checked by MS Windows. So reformat into ext4, and then you will need to set permissions and ownerschips to the entire drive or the folders where you want access as your user. The tool Disks allows to do that, including "taking ownership" of the entire drive.

Comment: The **Disks** tool solved my problem, so someone should answer this so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Disks** tool easily solved my problem.